The tablespace is created normally using PolarDB, but an error occurs when using it. How to solve it?
I am encountering an error when trying to use a tablespace in PolarDB. The tablespace creation works fine, but I get an error when attempting to create a table using the tablespace.
Here's how to reproduce the issue:

Use this project to build the image and create a container:

https://github.com/ApsaraDB/polardb-pg-docker-images/

Create a tablespace directory in the shared data directory:

cd /var/polardb/shared_datadir/pg_tblspc
mkdir abc


Create the tablespace successfully:

create tablespace tbs location '/var/polardb/shared_datadir/pg_tblspc/abc';


Attempt to create a table using the tablespace, which results in an error:

postgres=# create table t (id int) tablespace tbs; 
ERROR:  could not create directory "file-dio:///var/polardb/shared_datadir/pg_tblspc/16388/PG_15_202209061/5": No such file or directory

How can I resolve this issue and successfully create a table in the specified tablespace?
